# Help! First time setup password broken!

Tags: boot, grub2, login, password

I tried downloading Ubuntu 14.04 onto my old windows vista laptop. The installation went fine, but when i loaded it up for the first time I got to this screen:

Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS Linux tty1

Linux login:

password:

I can put in the login just fine, but when I click enter and attempt to input a password no matter which keys I press, nothing appears under password. By continually clicking enter I get this:

Login incorrect

Linux login:

password:

And the process continues on and on, making me unable to complete the first time boot up! I tried changing my password in the grub terminal, but it didn't do anything in the long run. Please help! I want to be able to use Ubuntu Desktop but I can't with this mysterious discrepancy!

Comment: It looks like you have installed a server version. That's why it loads to tty.

Comment: Your password not showing when you type it in is a security feature, which you can change to have the `***`s. But trust me, you are typing in your password, and if you type it correctly, and press ENTER, it will log you in, however the security feature means you just won't be able to see that you are typing it in.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing will show up as you type your password, this is an intentional security feature!

Make sure you type the password correctly, remember that Ubuntu is case-sensitive!

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed the server version then this is expected.

Although if you have not installed the server version then also this can happen. Your OS is unable to continue up to the six init levels required for normal startup. It is seemingly stuck at the first init run level which happens when something is broken.I suggest that instead of trying to salvage this situation you perform a fresh re-install of Ubuntu. Also a great precaution to avoid similar happenstance in future is to always check the MD5 Hash of your downloaded iso file with that provided at the Download Page [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes). It is there for a reason. Read more about init levels [here](http://www.debianadmin.com/debian-and-ubuntu-linux-run-levels.html).